# Haskell :: The Use of Brackets in Recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm just wondering, for recursion example:

```
squaresRec :: [Double] -> [Double]   
squaresRec [] = []                       
squaresRec (x:xs) = x*x : squaresRec xs
```

Why on the recursive case, there is no bracket? Shouldn't it suppose to be like this:

```
squaresRec :: [Double] -> [Double]   
squaresRec [] = []                       
squaresRec [x:xs] = x*x : squaresRec xs
```

I know this will not work. But just wondering the explanation behind it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`[]`** matches the empty list.

**`[1]`** matches a list containing exactly one element, and that must be a number equal to one. Note that `[1]` is actually syntactic sugar for `(1:[])`, i.e. what this really matches is: a list beginning with the number `1`, followed by a list that is empty... which is just a complicated way of saying “a list containing the single element `1`”.

**`(x:xs)`** matches a list that begins with `x`, followed by `xs` (and that may contain any number of elements, possibly zero). I.e. this pattern matches any list with **at least** one element.

**`[x:xs]`** matches again a list which contains **exactly** one element, and that element should match the pattern `(x:xs)`. (Which doesn't make sense even type-wise, because your lists contain `Double`-numbers, not lists.)

Comment: I was confuse with the use of (1, 2, 3) with [1, 2, 3] which I think it represent a tuple and a list.

I did think why not do it this way [(x:xs)]? It is a list that is not empty [] but has a list that start with x and the rest is xs.

Comment: You can write `[(x:xs)]`, but the parentheses don't make any difference there. Generally, parentheses only influence how the code is _parsed_, but `[...]` already parses everything within into one AST node anyway, so it doesn't matter whether you write `[x:xs]` or `[(x:xs)]` or even something like `(([((((x):((xs)))))]))`. Square brackets OTOH do make a difference, namely, they trigger the syntax desugaring. `[x:xs]` is sugar for `(x:xs):[]`, whereas `x:xs` is already desugared.

Comment: The parenthesis are not the tuple constructor. They're here to isolate the several `,` (commas) which are the real tuple builders

Comment: @Uniaika that doesn't seem like a particularly useful concept considering that commas for tuples are never valid anywhere without parentheses (whereas an actual building operator would be). The tuple constructor syntactically doesn't really fit with anything else in Haskell land, which is arguably the reason it exists in the first place (because it's somewhat nicer than writing `Tuple3 1 2 3`)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem because I'm coming from Erlang.

The thing to understand is that the [head|tail] pattern we have in Erlang is actually translated by the `cons` function in Haskell, which is the `:` operator. The parenthesis are just here to isolate the function parameters, like (3+4) would do.

I know it's tempting to ask "why though???" and that it visually makes more sense, but `:` is how we build (and separate when pattern-matching) the head and the tail of a linked list.

Comment: It does seem to make “visually sense” to many people, but I've never understood why. I find it much more intuitive that everything written within square brackets are single _elements_, not lists. In particular, I find the Matlab convention that `[a b]` can denote `a ++ b` completely crazy.

Comment: eh, Erlang was my first programming language so I that's how I learned lists and lists comprehension. To me, the square brackets indicate a visual context for lists, in which you can do stuff like cons and list comprehensions.